# Deerclops fighting tactics (2 players, one being newbie)

Tags: dont-starve-together

I am playing Don't Starve Together, with a friend. I'm very experienced at the game, while my friend has played about 50 hours or so.

It's our first winter, and [Deerclops](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Deerclops) is spawning (we hear the sound). I've read he has double the hp he normally has, which makes me wonder if we will be able to kill him before sanity drops to 0 and [Terrorbeaks](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Creature) destroy us. Keep in mind that my friend is not so experienced at kiting so I might have to kill Deerclops by myself.

**Coordination might be a big problem**. Whoever gets the last hit on Deerclops will become his new target. So, if my friend gets the last hit, and he starts running like a rabbit... I'll be chasing Deerclops who will be chasing my friend. Funny :D but deadly, since Deerclops will be dodging my hits while i might get hit by his AoE, and will lose sanity as well.

**My thoughts**:
I could try solo him, while my friend stands in a safe distance and keeps the fires going, or makes me a new armor or gets me some food. I have 3 Tentacle Spikes and a Walking Cane, 2 Log Suits (and *unfortunately* 60 hunger and 60 sanity, and 2 minutes until night starts).

In Don't Starve (alone) i can easily kill Deerclops. Here, however, under current conditions, I'm not so sure about it.

---

**Questions**:

-Would my plan work?
-What is a safer way to kill Deerclops?
-Should i not risk (since i m not fully prepared) and just ignore Deerclops this winter?

Answer (score 2):

This may sound like cheating but if you're the host of the Don't Starve Together map/ session, there is an option for you to turn on `"saves"` in the `Manage Server` section (after you select the world you want to play on). You can set the day interval at which the game world would save (storing all the information/ data/ items you have).

If you enable this feature and make sure you have at least one save file, you can attempt to take out the Deerclops. If you fail, simply revert back to the previous day. That way you will know how you can improve on your strategy and what exactly you need to prepare for in the future when or if you wish to take out the Deerclops again.

Answer (score 0):

So What you should always do is have a person that can tank with good armor and high health. His job isnt just to stand there, He has to try and distract and and hit the deer-clops whist the other runs up, hits, and runs away and the tanker always gets the final hit. like a one two punch kinda thing, and to be extra safe, let the tanker run up let the deer clops try and hit then go in. Don't always do it consecutively. I will try and make a video on it and give a link. :)